# Using isc-dhcp-server, multiple IPs for same MAC

Tags: networking, 18.04, network-manager, dhcp

I am running a Ubuntu 18.04 Server with isc-dhcp-server software (version 4.4.x) which is setup to distribute IPs on my local network.

The '''dhcpd.conf''' is very simple and only broadcast IPs to a single subnet 
and local network.

The following commands are runned at the clients.

For each client and MAC, in my network I receive multiple IPs.
The result from running '''ifconfig''' yields that the ethernet-interface connected to the network holds one IP. 
(This might be because not all IP from this interface is displayed in '''ifconfig''').

Running '''ip address show''', lists a more detailed view and lists all of the IPs allocated to that interfaces.
Why is it that ethernet-interface holds several IPs? 
I cannot find any setting whom state that IP aliasing is present.
What type command should I run to sort out this problem?

My goal is to supply each unique MAC with one IP and one hostname (which I find difficult).

Any help is much appreciated.

Regards,
P.

Update #1:

The server´s IP is 192.168.1.1.

dhcpd.conf (@dhcp-server):

```
    #dchpd.conf
    default-lease-time 600;
    max-lease-time 7200;
    ddns-update-style none;
    authoritative;
    allow booting;
    allow bootp;
    subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
       range 192.168.1.10 192.168.1.20;
       filename "pxelinux.0"
    }
```

At the client, I also ran `nmcli device show` and noticed that the different IPs obtained by the client where listed, but there where no information regarding the dhcp.

Comment: mac based IP address allocation is actually quite easy. Edit your question and post your config file, then maybe we can help.

Comment: Thank you, updated the question.

Comment: See [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/607581/internet-sharing-with-static-mac-addr-to-ip-mapping/607659#607659) for a MAC based dhcpd.conf file.

Comment: Thank you. Will get back asap with result.

Comment: Thank you, it works. I also found that a netplan-setting was active, resulting in an additional IP.